# Chrome: Seems to add an invisible border when hovering over a tr

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, html-table, hover

My Chrome seems to have some problems with hovering over a tr element inside a table. Every other browser seems to work fine. (Chrome version 15.0.874.121 m).

I'm executing the event with jQuery (and yes, I need to use Javascript as I need to alter the table in realtime when the user hovers over it, so :hover is not an option, and even so, the problem seems to happen there as well).

Here's the code in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="da" lang="da">
    <head>
        <title>:(</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("tr").hover(function () {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#aaaaaa");
                }, function() {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#555555");
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            table, table tr, table tr td {
                border: 0px;
                border-spacing: 0px;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            table {
                width: 500px;
            }
            table tr {
                background-color: #555555;
                color: #FFFFFF;
            }
            /*table tr:hover {
                background-color: #aaaaaa;
            }*/
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td>test1</td><td>this1</td><td>in1</td><td>chrome1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>test2</td><td>this2</td><td>in2</td><td>chrome2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>test3</td><td>this3</td><td>in3</td><td>chrome3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>test4</td><td>this4</td><td>in4</td><td>chrome4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>test5</td><td>this5</td><td>in5</td><td>chrome5</td></tr>
            <tr><td>test6</td><td>this6</td><td>in6</td><td>chrome6</td></tr>
            <tr><td>test7</td><td>this7</td><td>in7</td><td>chrome7</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the code running on a webserver:

http://www.jalsoedesign.net/test/tabletest/tabletest.php

When hovering over the very end (or start) of the individual TD elements (even though the function uses the TR), it seems to call the "onmouseleave" javascript function. I've tried with onmouseover/onmouseout as well, and nothing seems to make a difference. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Figured it out. For some *odd* reason, adding a "position: relative" on the td element seems to fix it. I'm unaware of why this happens, so if anyone has a clue, feel free to give your input. :)

**UPDATE 2013-02-28:**

This does not seem to happen in current versions of Chrome.

Comment: I did not understand why *":hover is not an option"*?

Comment: First of all, it doesn't work either, and secondly I have to modify the TR contents, to change the colspan of certain TD elements.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought changing the background-color was the only thing you need to change.

Comment: No, it was just to create a simple HTML example :)

Comment: Have you tried the same thing with `border-collapse: separate;`? I have a hunch that this might fix it.

Comment: Check the question - I fixed it by adding a `position: relative` to the TD elements. `border-collapse: seperate;` does not make a difference.

Comment: Now you can wait until the cavalry arrives to explain why `position: relative;` makes any difference here. Or you can write that as an answer of your own and gather some up-votes. :)

Comment: Tried on chrome here (linux version), and didnt see the problem. Did you already try doing a css reset?

Comment: @Tomalak unforntually that requires 100 rep, which I do not yet have. :)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Writing an answer does not require 100 rep. :)

Comment: @Tomalak No, you're right. But if you're under 100 rep you have to wait 8 hours after the thread is posted (I'm pretty sure that SO came up with that error when I tried).

Comment: Oh. Allright. 100 rep is a long time ago for me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previously mentioned, but to not leave this answerless, the solution was to add a `position: relative` to all the TD elements.